# How can I store composer cache in a volume during when building a docker?

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I am using this Dockerfile to create an image with my PHP application dependencies:

```
FROM composer:latest AS composer

COPY ./ ./

VOLUME composer-cache:/tmp/

RUN composer install

FROM php:7.1-fpm

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq5 libpq-dev libmemcached11 libmemcached-dev libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmagickwand-dev unzip --no-install-recommends && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql && \
    pecl install imagick && \
    echo extension=imagick.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/imagick.ini && \
    apt-get remove -y libpq-dev libmemcached-dev libmagickwand-dev && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get autoclean -y

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

COPY ./ ./

COPY --from=composer /app/vendor ./vendor
```

For faster build and reducing network activity I want to store composer's cache in the volume called `composer-cache`. But composer does not store anything data in that volume.

I checked a official composer Dockerfile and noticed it's exports `COMPOSER_HOME` environment variable points to `/tmp` directory. I think is enough to store cache outside from container, but this is not.

On every build composer downloads all dependencies again, and the volume remains empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the directive `VOLUME` creates a volume mountpoint **to be used at runtime**.

That volume is actually created when you execute `docker run`. During build time (`docker build`), that instruction **has no effect**.

But you can use new build time enhancements added for this kind of thing.

You need to add the following to your Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM composer:latest AS composer

COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/tmp/cache composer install --prefer-dist --no-suggest

### your next build stage...
```

This will result in speedier `install` execution after the first time.

To gain *download* speed (which may make the above kinda relatively moot), you can use [Prestssimo](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo). This is a composer plugin that makes that composer download are performed *in parallel* instead of sequentially.

**(Note, with Composer 2 Prestissimo is obsolete, since composer itself performs this type of download optimisation).**

You'd end up with

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM composer:latest AS composer
RUN composer global require hirak/prestissimo

COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/tmp/cache composer install --prefer-dist  --no-suggest

### your next build stage...
```

You would then call your build process like this:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
```

**[It is not currently possible](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6440) to use docker-compose to enable buildkit.** But with a bit of foreplanning you can build your images first, and declare those images in your docker-compose files for orchestration.

I find that simply using Prestissimo is enough as not to need additional cache layers, but you'll need to check what's best for your scenario.

Comment: Hi, Ivan! Thanks for your participation.

Fast googling tells me that:
Experimental features needs be activated in docker's daemon config;
`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` enviroment variable need to be exported before running `docker build` command;
Container need's to builded with directly calling a `docker build` command, building trough `docker-compose` is not currently possibe;

After these three steps, i can succesfully build this container, and cache really stores, and uses in next builds. Whoa! Thank you!

Comment: But a have a question: before this features stabilized, what developers uses for storing compose cache now? Are there any other options, maybe not so convenient?

Comment: True, it can't be used with docker-compose directly, but you can always first `docker build`, and use those images within docker-compose. There is no other caching method that I'm aware of, I do not think it is really possible unless you do the caching outside the container and copy it to the container before build (really ugly). But even without cache, the use of Prestissimo would speed up your installs by a **a lot**. Also, add the `--prefer-dist` to your install command, that would also speed things up a bit.

Comment: I will hope that this build method is quickly stabilized. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dockers caching instead of composers caching, by restructuring a little.

Imagine this Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-cli
COPY --from=composer:2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
```

By installing the dependencies **before** copying the apps files, you have the dependencies in a separate cached layer that only changes when the dependencies change. You could do it like this:

```
FROM php:8.1-cli
COPY --from=composer:2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
WORKDIR /app
COPY composer.json composer.lock .
RUN composer install --no-dev
COPY . /app
RUN composer dumpautoload
```